# I have different number of quotes to concatinate so make a complete Xpath but getting error,

Tags: python, selenium

I am storing 2 strings and concatinating to make a complete xpath for for script

```
    rowc = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="rgRow"]|//*[@class="rgAltRow"]')
    i = len(rowc)
    extstr1 = "//*[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__
    extstr2 = "]/td[13]"
    for i in range(0):
        extval = driver.find_element_by_xpath(extstr1+i+extstr2)
```

I am getting the below error :

```
  extstr1 = "//*[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

Comment: `"//*[@id="` is a string. What comes next, python does not understand. If you use `"` inside of a string, I suggest enclosing this string with `'` and vice versa. But in this case `extstr1 = "//*[@id=m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__"` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
extstr1 = "//*[@id='m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__'"
extstr2 = "]/td[13]"
```

You need to change the `"` in extstr1 into `'`